# UNION Error when creating a Veiw

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a problem with creating a view. Saying: Expression must be of same data type. This occurs at name.

```
  CREATE VIEW V_DETAILS_BY_CATEGORY AS 

    SELECT category_id, name
        FROM category 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT DISTINCT(category_id), COUNT(film_id)
        FROM film_category
        GROUP BY category_id;
```

EDIT:

The exact proplem I have is I want to Join the resutls from the two select Statment using category_id.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this view? There might be a better way.

Comment: @Bob I want to create a view with the category type, cat_id, Number of movies in each category and the average rating of the category

Comment: Please give me more details about your tables. A join is the way to go. You can look into what okaram said to get you started.

Comment: Table film  --- >(film_id)
Table film_category --- >(Film_id, cat_id)
Category (cat_id)

Comment: These 3 tables I am using

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve Oracle error ORA-01790?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863112/how-to-resolve-oracle-error-ora-01790)

Comment: Unrelated but: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. `distinct (category_id), count(film_id)` is the same as `distinct category_id, count(film_id)`. It always operates on *all* columns of a select statement. Additionally: combined with your `group by` it makes even less sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count(film_id) is a number, while name is (probably) some sort of string. You probably want to do a JOIN, not union (union takes rows that have the same structure from two different tables). Also, the distinct is not needed, since you're doing a group by.

You probably want something like

```
SELECT category_id, category_name, COUNT(film_id)
FROM film_category JOIN category USING category_id
GROUP BY category_id, category_name;
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it comes up as missing a key word

Comment: Unfortunately, not all dbms allow for USING ; try ON film_category.category_id= category.category_id instead of 'using category_id'

Comment: Also, don't have an oracle server at hand; may need parenthesis in using, using(category_id) ... I'm sure Oracle supported using ...

Answer (score 2):

Unions must contain the same types of data.

If you convert your count to whatever data type the "name" field is, it might work.

```
SELECT category_id, name FROM category 
UNION ALL 
SELECT category_id, TO_CHAR(COUNT(film_id)) FROM film_category
GROUP BY category_id;
```

But, I agree with okaram, you might actually be looking for a JOIN, not a UNION ALL, which is why I asked about the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using Same Type of data for Column in Union

```
CREATE VIEW V_DETAILS_BY_CATEGORY AS 
        SELECT category_id, name
            FROM category 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT category_id, CAST(COUNT(film_id) AS NVARCHAR(100))
            FROM film_category
            GROUP BY category_id;

    -------------- OR      
        SELECT category_id, name
            FROM category 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT category_id, LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(COUNT(film_id))))
            FROM film_category
            GROUP BY category_id;
```

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It's an operator that works on all columns in the select list.

Comment: Yes - lose the distinct, you're just confusing the issue.