# Datatype Error ORA-01790

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have an error with datatype:

> ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

I already check all the datatype same already.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY, 'Projection', '1', OPEN_BALANCE,
  PRINC_REPAYMENT, INTEREST, PAR_PREPAYMENT, FULL_REDEMPTION, REDRAW_AMOUNT, PRIN_DEFAULTS,
  PRIN_RECOVERY, PRIN_DEL, INTE_DEL, DEL_PRIN_COLL, DEL_INT_COLL, CLOSE_PRIN_BAL, EXT_ID,
  LAS_ACTIVE_FLG, PROD_ID, ASSET_TYP_ID, CPT_ID, ACCRETION, CASHFLOW_DT 
FROM FACT_PWOR_CASHFLOW
WHERE ACTUAL_FLG = 'Y' AND LATEST_PROJ_IND = '0' AND LAS_ACTIVE_FLG = 'Y'
UNION
(SELECT CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY_COLL, 'Actual', '1', SUM(OPENING_BALANCE) SUM_OPEN_BAL,
    SUM(MI_PRINCIPLE) SUM_MI_PRIN, SUM(MI_INTEREST) SUM_MI_INTER, SUM(PARTIAL_PREPAYMENT) SUM_PAR_PREPAY,
    SUM(FULL_REDEMPTION) SUM_FULL_REDEM, SUM(TTL_AMT_REDRAW) SUM_TTL_AMT,
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', SUM(CLOSING_BALANCE) SUM_CLOS_BAL, '0', 'Y',
    PROD_ID, ASSET_TYPE_ID, CPT_ID, '0', COLLECTION_START_DT
FROM FACT_PWOR_COLLECTION
WHERE LAS_ACTIVE_FLG = 'Y'
GROUP BY CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY_COLL, PROD_ID, ASSET_TYPE_ID, CPT_ID, COLLECTION_START_DT);
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your question to make it clearer?

Comment: When I run this query, it gave me this error "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression". I already check all the datatype match already.

Comment: I would suggest you also add some sample data with the tables design, it would help us more to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Oracle error ORA-01790?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863112/how-to-resolve-oracle-error-ora-01790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a set operation like `UNION` in your case, all the matching columns' data type in both tables `FACT_PWOR_CASHFLOW` and `FACT_PWOR_COLLECTION` must match.

As an example, If data type of column `ACCRETION` in the first `SELECT` statement may be `integer`, while the corresponding column which is stated as `'0'` in the second `SELECT` statement is of `string type` , then `DataType Error` occurs.

Remove all columns inthe SELECT lists and then Try to add columns for both SELECT statements step by step by starting from the first one `CONTRACT_ID`.

Comment: It is really silly mistake. I initialize my 0 in ' ' so it become char like you said. Thank you Barbaros!

Comment: @AzimHakimi Thank you, too brother.